# Which version is this? Compare a bare source tree with the repository

Tags: git

I have a source tree (of a PHP application) which was rsynced out of a git repository at a point in time.

Can I find the matching version in the repo (the last commit which is present in the source tree)? - What if there were some minor modifications to this exported, untracked version of the source tree?

It should be possible if the terms are defined correctly. Is there a tool or a builtin git utility to solve this problem?

Comment: @CharlesB I have a non version-controlled source tree. Also: devconsole's answer already seems more resource-friendly than any of the answers there. - Though I'm still waiting for a possibly less brute-force solution.

Comment: the duplicate also deals with a non version-controlled source tree :) and devconsole's answer is quite the same as the duplicate accepted answer. I don't think you can have a non-brute force solution

Answer (score 3):

There may be better solutions but you could copy the exported source tree back to the git working directory (without committing it) and then compare with previous revisions in a for loop. Here's an example on how this could work with a bash script:

```
for ((i=1; i<100; i++)); do
  echo $i
  git diff --shortstat HEAD~$i
done
```

Then look for the minimum number of changes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a project of mine. I did

```
rsync -avz [GIT_REPO_BARE] local-copy
```

then I `cd` to local-copy and I run a `git log`. Luckily, I had some commits not yet pushed to the remote git repo, so I pushed them. Then I simply looked for the commit the commit id I previously found earlier with `git log`. Is that what you looked for?

Comment: The source tree to compare is not version controlled. From `git log` I assume you also rsynced the .git directory (so in your version it is version controlled).